# want to replace .index.php?backLinks_free_Backlinks=1&totalRows_free_Backlinks=7 part by /backLinks_free_Backlinks/1 from my url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have a link look like this
http://backlinks.cheapratedomain.com/index.php?backLinks_free_Backlinks=1&totalRows_free_Backlinks=7

want to replace .index.php?backLinks_free_Backlinks=1&totalRows_free_Backlinks=7 this part by /backLinks_free_Backlinks/1 using .htaccess

after replacing link will be look like this

http://backlinks.cheapratedomain.com/backLinks_free_Backlinks/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^backLinks_free_Backlinks/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?backLinks_free_Backlinks=$1&totalRows_free_Backlinks=7 [L,QSA]
```

You can remove the `&totalRows_free_Backlinks=7` bit from the target if you don't need it.